# Why can't I build the deb package of my electron app? (fakeroot: nested operation not yet supported)

Tags: electron-forge, fakeroot

I am trying to build a `.deb` package of my electron app as described on the [electron homepage](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-packaging) and on the [electron-forge homepage](https://www.electronforge.io/config/makers/deb).
Unfortunately, I am getting the error

> fakeroot: nested operation not yet supported

It seems that

> attempt is made to run fakeroot from within a fakeroot environment
> as documented on the [fakeroot package homepage](https://wiki.debian.org/FakeRoot)

Is there any way I can still make my `.deb` package?

I am running Ubuntu 22.04, node v14.18.3 and @electron-forge/maker-deb@6.1.1